# Lattice points near a curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, lattices

Bombieri and Pila had [a well known bound](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/pila/Ovals.pdf) for the count of lattice points on an algebraic curve in the plane. Does it generalize to a bound for the count of lattice points *near* (say within a distance of $\delta=o(1)$) an algebraic curve? Is it obvious that we only need to add $O(\delta L)$ to the Bombieri-Pila count, where $L$ is the length of the curve? Or do we have to use the weaker bound of Swinnerton-Dyer?

**Edit**: To put things in more context, $O(\delta L)$ is the "expected" number of lattice points near the curve if the curve is situated randomly in the plane. The Bombieri-Pila bound can be thought of as arising from the arithmetic structure of the algebraic curve. My question then amounts to: do the expected count and the arithmetic count together fully account for the lattice points near an algebraic curve?

Comment: what is relation between $\delta$ and $L$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Assume $\delta$ is very small.

Comment: See Huxley's paper: Huxley, M. N. The integer points close to a curve. Mathematika 36 (1989), no. 2, 198–215 (1990). (Reviewer: S. W. Graham) 11J54 (11J71)

This type of problem can also be approached by an extension of the Bombieri-Pila determinant method, due to Heath-Brown. This version is called the "approximate" determinant method. For example, see:

http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/47/2/270

and

Heath-Brown, D. R. Sums and differences of three kth powers. J. Number Theory 129 (2009), no. 6, 1579–1594

Comment: Also, Jing Jing Huang does a lot of work on this topic; searching his name on MathSciNet will likely be fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

See: MR2271609 (2007m:11092) Reviewed 
Huxley, Martin N.(4-CARD-SM); Sargos, Patrick(F-NANC-IE)
Points entiers au voisinage d'une courbe plane de classe Cn. II. (French. English, French summary) [Integral points near a plane curve of class Cn. II] 
Funct. Approx. Comment. Math. 35 (2006), 91–115. 
11J25 (11P21)

Comment: Is it about algebraic or smooth curves?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Actually both are helpful to me, but what I need most now is a French dictionary :).

Comment: @FanZheng There are more symbols than words there :) And yes, the paper is about smooth curves.